# AutoFS with Kerberos passing root UID instead of user UID at login, fails to mount

Tags: nfs, cifs, kerberos, autofs

On a Ubuntu 16.04 test VM, I can automount my homedir (as CIFS in this example, NFSv4 behaves similarly), but only *after* I have already logged in. Apparently, autofs is passing `UID=0` instead of my correct UID, thus is unable to obtain the service ticket (names, IP addresses changed below for privacy).

At login:

```
Sep 26 07:10:47 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: key description: cifs.spnego;0;0;39010000;ver=0x2;host=files.univ.edu;ip4=x.x.x.8;sec=krb5;uid=0x0;creduid=0x0;user=user;pid=0x4ba5
Sep 26 07:10:47 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: ver=2
Sep 26 07:10:47 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: host=files.univ.edu
Sep 26 07:10:47 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: ip=x.x.x.8
Sep 26 07:10:47 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: sec=1
Sep 26 07:10:47 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: uid=0
Sep 26 07:10:47 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: creduid=0
Sep 26 07:10:47 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: user=user
Sep 26 07:10:47 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: pid=19365
Sep 26 07:10:47 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: find_krb5_cc: scandir error on directory '/run/user/0': No such file or directory
Sep 26 07:10:47 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: find_krb5_cc: considering /tmp/krb5cc_386616_lPzqLb
Sep 26 07:10:47 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: find_krb5_cc: /tmp/krb5cc_386616_lPzqLb is owned by 386616, not 0
Sep 26 07:10:47 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: krb5_get_init_creds_keytab: -1765328203
Sep 26 07:10:47 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: handle_krb5_mech: getting service ticket for files.univ.edu
Sep 26 07:10:47 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: cifs_krb5_get_req: unable to get client principal name
Sep 26 07:10:47 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: handle_krb5_mech: failed to obtain service ticket (-1765328189)
Sep 26 07:10:47 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: Unable to obtain service ticket
Sep 26 07:10:47 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: Exit status -1765328189
Sep 26 07:10:47 ubuntu-ad kernel: [639027.427376] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -126
```

After logging in:

```
Sep 26 07:13:32 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: key description: cifs.spnego;0;0;39010000;ver=0x2;host=files.univ.edu;ip4=x.x.x.9;sec=krb5;uid=0x5e638;creduid=0x5e638;user=user;pid=0x4c28
Sep 26 07:13:32 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: ver=2
Sep 26 07:13:32 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: host=files.univ.edu
Sep 26 07:13:32 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: ip=x.x.x.9
Sep 26 07:13:32 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: sec=1
Sep 26 07:13:32 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: uid=386616
Sep 26 07:13:32 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: creduid=386616
Sep 26 07:13:32 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: user=user
Sep 26 07:13:32 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: pid=19496
Sep 26 07:13:32 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: find_krb5_cc: considering /tmp/krb5cc_386616_SsLxA7
Sep 26 07:13:32 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: find_krb5_cc: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_386616_SsLxA7 is valid ccache
Sep 26 07:13:32 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: handle_krb5_mech: getting service ticket for files.univ.edu
Sep 26 07:13:32 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: handle_krb5_mech: obtained service ticket
Sep 26 07:13:32 ubuntu-ad cifs.upcall: Exit status 0
```

How can I get autofs to pass the correct UID/CredUID at login?